# removing trailing slash and non-www to www - using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, trailing-slash

I'm facing an issue with .htacess when combining 2 mod_rewrite at the same time:

- remove trailing slash
- redirect non-www to www

Here is my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

They worked perfectly when I just used one of them, but when i put them together, the page just keep loading like forever.

Please help me to find a way that can use both of them in the same .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /
#Non www to www without trailing slash
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain\.com)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/?[^/]+)/?$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L,OR]
RewriteRule  .* http://www.domain.com [R=301,L]
```

Results:

`http://domain.com/aa/` to `http://ww.domain.com/aa`

`http://domain.com/aa/bb/` to `http://ww.domain.com/aa/bb`, etc.

All except `http://domain.com/` that always will be `http://www.domain.com/`with trailing slash

Comment: Why is not working? If you write `http://domain.com` it will take you to `http://www.domain.com`. If you write `http://domain.com/` it will take you to `http://www.domain.com` As far as I can see, that's exactly what your asking. Here it is: 
    remove trailing slash
    redirect non-www to www

Comment: its not working in case: www.domain.com/abc/ (abc can be a folder or just a url rewirted), its not remove the trailing slash.
Any chance to remove this kind of trailing slash too?

Comment: Updated my answer, should work with any path. If it doesn't, please let me know to test it.

Answer (score 1):

**NON-WWW URLS TO WWW USING HTACCESS:**

You can add the following code to your .htaccess file, you can find it in your website root directory, if you don't find it you can copy this in a text editor and save it as .htaccess, then upload it.

**p.s.:** Make sure that you backup the .HTACCESS file before you proceed. Incorrect codes can lead to 500 errors.

```
    RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**Remove trailing slash**

Be careful when turning off the trailing slash. If your host has mod_dir enabled, make sure that you turn off the directory slash, which is enabled by default. This directive will add a trailing slash at the end of a directory regardless of the rules you set up. To disable this, add this to the top of your htaccess file:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

Your browser and even your server, by default, add a trailing slash to a directory. It is done for a reason. If you must strip the trailing slash though, this is how you would do it:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```